# What's the English idiom for "it was out of one's destiny"?

Tags: idiom-requests

What do you call something that will not happen because is contradicts the fate? For example, an anecdote. 
"One day, a train rushed out from poit A to point B. Simultaneously, another train started moving from point B to point A. They both had high speed, and the crash could have been awful. But the trains never met. Just because ". 
Thank you!

Comment: "It wasn 't in the stars" is a common expression.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the expression ***it was not meant to happen:***

***[It was meant to:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mean)***

> 11. verb [usually passive]:
>
>     - If you say that something was meant to happen, you believe that it was made to happen by God or fate, and did not just happen by chance.

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: Or *wasn't meant to be*

Comment: _It wasn't in the cards._ 
and
_It wasn't in the stars._
References to fortune telling

Comment: @Jas.MacOisdealbha - you should post an answer, rather than a comment

Answer (score 1):

A common expression that I have heard used is 'written in the stars'.​ Or in the context of the question 'not written in the stars'.

> If you believe that something is written in the stars, you believe that it will be made to happen by a force that controls the future

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/written-in-the-stars)

Shakespeare disagreed, however. Or, at least, he put disagreement in the mouth of
Cassius :

> The fault, dear Brutus, is not in our stars,
>
> But in ourselves, that we are underlings.

[Shakespeare Concordance - Julius Caesar : Act I, Scene 2, line 231](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&searchtype=exact&works%5B%5D=juliuscaesar&keyword1=stars&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr)

Note: The expression 'It is not in the stars to hold our destiny, but in ourselves' is a common misquote of the above line. See [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-this-quote-mean-%E2%80%9CIt-is-not-in-the-stars-to-hold-our-destiny-but-in-ourselves%E2%80%9D).